# DBeaver: how to switch database in SQL editor?

Tags: dbeaver

I'm using DBeaver with PostgreSQL. I can open a new SQL editor with <kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>

But I have multiple databases in my PostgreSQL. How can I have the SQL editor run against another database?

The following doesn't work:

```sql
use <db name>;
select * from <table name>;
```

[image: dbeaver ui]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can change the currently selected database when you create new sql tabs by selecting it from the dropdown.

[image: dbeaver change database]

When you do so be sure to double-click on the schema you want to bring into focus. Then you can open new sql editors with `ctrl+]`.

Comment: In v6.3.0 this drop-down doesn't work fine and change selected DB is almost impossible.

Answer (score 26):

You can set a different database as active in your current connection by right-clicking in the Database Navigator pane and selecting "Set active", below I am switching from 'postgres' to my 'report_service' DB
(this is version 6.1.2, not sure about other versions)

[image]

EDIT:
I have  recently upgraded to version 6.3.5 and this now has "Set as default" in the dropdown rather than "Set active" but this seems to be roughly the same behaviour

Comment: In v6.3.0 is the same option.

Comment: This does not work for me. With DBeaver 7.3.0 the command "Set as default" does not change the current database. Verified with `SELECT current_database();`.
The other solution from @harry-moreno works well.

Comment: That's interesting, I'm now on 7.3.2 and it still works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution.
Press Ctrl+9 and choose your destiny-base...

[image: Press Ctrl+9 and chooz]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The answer from  @harry_moreno is perfect and bulls eye to the raised question. I have looked for month regularly having a go in Google but came up with nothing ... until now! Ctrl-9. Thanks  Harry Moreno!